# Nuxt axios - how to reject a success response to error

Tags: axios, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I define axios like below

```
$axios.onResponse((response) => {
   if (response.data.status == 500}
      return Promise.reject(response)
   }
})
$axios.onError((err) => {
   console.log(err)
})
```

and in `fetch` i call

```
async fetch () {
   await this.$axios.$get('myapi')
}
```

but i get error like

```
RangeError
Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

I try to reject a success response to error but it not working in ssr. How to fix that thank.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, using `try-catch` statements are preferred over event handlers (where appropriate).

Try something like this:

```
async fetch() {
    try {
        const response = await this.$axios.$get('myapi');
        if (response.data.status == 500) {
            throw new Error("Some error message");
        } else {
            // Success action here
        }
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}
```

Is there any particular reason you're returning a rejected Promise when you get a 500 error? Is there any reason not to throw a generalized error message instead?